# How to connect Mac terminal with EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using mac terminal and I want to connect my machine with server instance EC2 in aws with SSH. Since I am using Mac OS X is not necessary to use PUTTY. The problem is that when I download the key it is with extension .ppk but when i need to run it on terminal i need to use a command in which i have to use .pem extension . I tried to run it in that way and it said to me permission denied. Can someone help me what to do in this case? Do i have to change the permission or to convert my key from .ppk to .ppm?

Comment: There you go -> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html @enio-marku. Thanks google

Answer (score 20):

You need to know the .pem file folder you download, and then follow steps below:

1. download the keypair(.pem file)
2. cd to keypair(.pem file) location (Note that you can use absolute path name for key pair instead)
3. chmod 400 [your_key_name].pem (Note that to make SSH work, your key must not be publicly viewable. Use this command if needed.)
4. ssh -i "[your_key_name].pem" ec2-user@[your ec2 dns name]

Comment: This is not the correct answer the use has a PPK file it needs to be converted to PEM first then the above steps will work.

Comment: On a mac you can also right click the file, go to "Get Info" remove permissions for "Staff", set "Everyone" to "No Access" and make sure no one other than you is there.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to convert your "ppk" file to "pem" file follow this steps.

http://www.ramsmusings.com/2014/02/20/converting-a-putty-ppk-file-to-a-pem-file-for-accessing-aws-ec2-instances/

After you convert connect to the instance using the SSH command and converted "pem" file.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

Answer (score 0):

#### Quick answer

Instead of working directly with SSH keys I would consider working with [AWS ec2-instance-connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html).

It saves you the the management of the SSH keys and is much safer then sharing SSH keys for each EC2 machine between team members.

After authentication with the aws credentials (by referring to a profile in `.aws/config` file or [using environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html) ) you can connect to the instance very easily by providing the instance ID:

```
./bin/mssh <instance-ID>
```

Installation of this tool can be done via [pip](https://pypi.org/project/ec2instanceconnectcli/) or directly from the [github repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-ec2-instance-connect-cli).

---

#### Additional information

Amazon EC2 Instance Connect provides a simple and secure way to connect to your instances using Secure Shell (SSH). 
**With EC2 Instance Connect, you use AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) policies and principles to control SSH access to your instances, removing the need to share and manage SSH keys.**

When you connect to an instance using EC2 Instance Connect, the Instance Connect API pushes a one-time-use SSH public key to the instance metadata where it remains for 60 seconds. An IAM policy attached to your IAM user authorizes your IAM user to push the public key to the instance metadata.

The SSH daemon uses AuthorizedKeysCommand and AuthorizedKeysCommandUser, which are configured when Instance Connect is installed, to look up the public key from the instance metadata for authentication, and connects you to the instance.

You can use Instance Connect to connect to your Linux instances using a

1. browser-based client,
2. the Amazon EC2 Instance Connect CLI,
3. or the SSH client of your choice.

(*) Amazon Linux 2 2.0.20190618 or later and Ubuntu 20.04 or later comes preconfigured with EC2 Instance Connect.
For other supported Linux distributions, you must set up Instance Connect for every instance that will support using Instance Connect. This is a one-time requirement for each instance.

---

Links:
[Connect using EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html#ec2-instance-connect-connecting-ec2-cli)
[Securing your bastion hosts with Amazon EC2 Instance Connect](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/securing-your-bastion-hosts-with-amazon-ec2-instance-connect/)